# How can I extract certain elements from a string?

Tags: python

Here is the string that I want to extract elements from.
a and b are names of the team.
I want to extract the elements so I can write it into a CSV file in the forms of 'City', 'Team Name', 'Sport', 'Team Ranking', and 'Number of Times Picked'.
Any suggestions?
Edit: How to do it without using pandas?

Comment: Why do u wanna do it without `pandas`? `pandas` is the best library for such tasks.

Comment: Are u restricted from using `pandas`? Pls reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is to use `python` regular expressions with the `re` package. To find the sports team, for instance, you can do this:

```py
import re

value = "Sport: NFL, Name: San Francisco a, Rank: 0, Count: 3, \
    Sport: NFL, Name: Seattle b, Rank: 0, Count: 1"

pattern = re.compile('Sport: \w*')
results = re.findall(pattern, value) #.split(':')[1:]
print(results)
```

This results in the following output: `['Sport: NFL', 'Sport: NFL']`. Now you can iterate through the list as you see fit.

Here's all the `re` patterns you'll need to complete this problem:

```py
sports_pattern = re.compile('Sport: \w*')
name_pattern = re.compile('Name: \w*')
rank_pattern = re.compile('Rank: \w*')
count_pattern = re.compile('Count: \w*')
```

Comment: Much appreciated pal!

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

lst = ['Sport: NFL, Name: San Francisco a, Rank: 0, Count: 3',
       'Sport: NFL, Name: Seatle b, Rank: 0, Count: 1']

final = {}

for x in range(len(lst)):
    details_lst = (''.join(lst[x].split(':')).split(','))
    for index,elem in enumerate(details_lst):
        if index != 1:
            key = elem.strip().split(' ')[0]
            value = ' '.join(elem.strip().split(' ')[1:])
            final.setdefault(key, []).append(value)
        else:
            keys = ['City','Name']
            values = ' '.join(elem.strip().split(' ')[1:-1]),elem.strip().split(' ')[-1]
            for index, key in enumerate(keys):
                final.setdefault(key,[]).append(values[index])

columns = ['Sport','City','Team Name','Team Ranking','Number of Times Picked']
df = pd.DataFrame(final)
df.columns = columns
print(df)
df.to_csv("D:\\Details.csv", index = False)
```

Output:

```
  Sport           City Team Name Team Ranking Number of Times Picked
0   NFL  San Francisco         a            0                      3
1   NFL         Seatle         b            0                      1
```

Screenshot of the `csv` file:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Have a good one!

Answer (score -1):

Use the python built in split method to break the string into chunks broken at your specified delimiter and store it in a list. Use pandas library to create a dataframe from the the list. And then use Pandas (Dataframe.to_csv() method) to dump the data into a CSV File.
Read more about the
split method here:- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-yzfxeMBe1s
Pandas :- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CmorAWRsCAw&list=PLeo1K3hjS3uuASpe-1LjfG5f14Bnozjwy